# 'ls -1' : how to list filenames without extension

Tags: shell, grep, ls

`ls -1` lists my elements like so:

```
foo.png
bar.png
foobar.png
...
```

I want it listed without the `.png` like so:

```
foo
bar
foobar
...
```

(the dir only contains `.png` files)

Can somebody tell me how to use `grep` in this case?

Purpose:
I have a text file where all the names are listed without the extension. I want to make a script that compares the text file with the folder to see which file is missing.

Comment: What if the directory contains other extensions, such as `.jpg` and `.zip`. Should those be shown or suppressed?

Comment: You want to be careful with a request like this.  Linux does not have filename extensions.  Linux has filenames that may or may not include a `.` in them.  Although the convention says to name your files with `.png` at the end, there is no reason why I can't have a png file named `foo.zip` or `my.picture.20160518` or just `mypic` .

Comment: @Otheus In my case it has only the same ending (.png). This makes the problem much easier.

Comment: @hymie I know, but my elements in that folder are all named with .png at the end.

Comment: What's an "extension"? That's not part of Unix file naming; it's carryover from VMS/NT/Windows whatever. And you youngsters get off my lawn, too. :)

Comment: Let's not overstate this. The OS treats extensions as simply being part of the file name, but plenty of unix programs pay attention to them, from the compiler to the GUI. The concept is most certainly not foreign to unix.

Comment: It is usually suggested to [avoid to parse the output of `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) and to pipe the output of `ls` and `find`, mainly because the possibility to incur in `newline`,` tab char in the file name. If the filename is `The new art of working on .png\NEWLINE files and other formats` many of the solution proposed will create problems.

Comment: @Hastur: But you'll certainly run into plenty more problems with filenames like that. Your advice is a bit like advising against shaking hands when meeting people because they might have ebola. Just get those files renamed.

Comment: @reinierpost  You make it too simple. Working in teams in different countries means that not always you can change the filename of another member. Even when you can, often it results in a _time consuming_ multiplication of the file versions number. What I said was really happened when a guy started to extract from a PDF images for a future use, and called them copying and pasting the title in the field of the name, just adding a progressive number. One of the title had `Image.png` and a newline after, then continued with other worlds... So __why to write something you know it will not works?__

Comment: @Hastur: You should be asking your team member, not me.

Comment: Colin, we need to know *why* you want to hide the extension:  it will give out names that will *not* correspond to the files (in windows, the extension is often unnecessary. In linux, an extension is just a part of the name, so taking it out truncates the name, giving a different name (and possible another file, or most probably no file at all behind that other name). So, please, give a bit of context (as your question could be a XYProblem. And if it is (or isn't !), giving the context would make it more satysfying for us, as we will then know that the answers we provide are meaningful)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I have a text file where where all the names are listed without the extension. I want to make a PHP script that compares the text file with the folder to see which file is missing.

Comment: @Colin: then you can now edit your question, including that latest comment of yours, so that the "please tell me how to use grep in that case" becomes much clearer ^^ (it wasn't).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You only need the shell for this job.

POSIXly:

```
for f in *.png; do
    printf '%s\n' "${f%.png}"
done
```

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- *.png(:r)
```

Comment: There's no need for `printf`; `echo ${f%.png}` will suffice.

Comment: @Conrad: using echo won't work properly in some cases, if file name start with dash or contain escaped sequences.

Comment: @DavidConrad: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/38906

Comment: @DavidConrad Additionally, I believe printf is built in, just like echo, someone correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 66):

```
ls -1 | sed -e 's/\.png$//'
```

The `sed` command removes (that is, it replaces with the empty string) any string `.png` found at the **end** of a filename.

The `.` is escaped as `\.` so that it is interpreted by `sed` as a literal `.` character rather than the regexp `.` (which means match any character).  The `$` is the end-of-line anchor, so it doesn't match `.png` in the middle of a filename.

Comment: I think the OP wants _any_ extension stripped, but probably only the "last one". So maybe modify your otherwise good answer with: `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'`

Comment: yes, that regexp would work in that case...but if the OP wants that, they should say so instead of specifically saying they "want it listed without the .png"

Comment: I asked OP for clarification.

Comment: The `-1` is not necessary, being the default here.

Comment: I prefer the pure-shell answer better, but upvoted because you actually explained all the parts of the command you used.

Comment: @jlliagre I agree with cas that the `-1` should be specified. It's only the default when pipe is turned on, which is a hidden surprise for some. So making it explicit helps understanding. I also do this in my scripts so I know what kind of output I'm expecting.

Comment: @cas you were right about OP's question

Comment: @jlliagre yes, but i prefer to be explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: __Warning__  In the case of a filename with the key (`.png`) before a newline char you will erase even that `.png` and not only the last one. It is better to avoid to pipe and parse the output of ls, it reserves often well hidden surprises... (some words and references more in the answer).

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to use bash:

```
for i in *; do echo "${i%.png}"; done
```

You should reach for `grep` when trying to find matches, not for removing/substituting for that `sed` is more appropriate:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png"  | sed 's/\.png$//'
```

Once you decide you need to create some subdirectories to bring order in your PNG files you can easily change that to:

```
find . -name "*.png"  | sed 's/\.png$//'
```

Comment: ls -1 | sed 's/.png//'  works great. Thank you!

Comment: The `find` _piped_ to `sed` solution can present some problems if you find a file with the key (`.png`) as a part of the name and just before  a newline character. It is better to avoid to pipe and parse the output of `find` or `ls`, it reserves often well hidden surprises... (some words and references more in the answer).

Comment: Probably replace `find` with something like `echo` in the last example. Not clear what purpose `find` serves there and results depend on directory structure (i.e. if you have a directory `files.png`)

Comment: @BroSlow Updated to something more sensible.

Answer (score 21):

I'd go for `basename` (assuming the GNU implementation):

```
basename --suffix=.png -- *.png
```

Comment: Note that if you want to use it in a pipe, you may find it helpful to use GNU basename's `-z` (or `--zero`) option to produce NUL-separated (instead of newline-separated) output.

Answer (score 17):

Another very similar answer (I'm surprised this particular variant hasn't appeared yet) is:

```
ls | sed -n 's/\.png$//p'
```

- You don't need the `-1` option to `ls`, since `ls` assumes that if the standard output isn't a terminal (it's a pipe, in this case).
- the `-n` option to `sed` means ‘don't print the line by default’
- the `/p` option at the end of the substitution means ‘...and print this line if a substitution was made’.

The net effect of that is to print out only those lines which end in `.png`, with the `.png` removed.  That is, this also caters to the slight generalisation of the OP’s question, where the directory doesn't contain only `.png` files.

The `sed -n` technique is often useful in cases where you might otherwise use grep+sed.

Comment: I like how the care you used to write your answer.  This solution will present  problems with filenames including __newlines__, it will not print the first part of the name.  Even more if it is a nastier one with the key (`.png`) before the newline char: in that case you will print that part without png, not erasing only the last part. It is often sugpugested to avoid to parse (and pipe) the output of `ls` because the problems can be hidden just where you are not thinking about...

Comment: @Hastur You're correct, in principle, and the famous page about [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) lists further problems (and solutions) when handing pathological filenames. But the best way of handling that is to _avoid having pathological filenames_ (doh!); and if you can't, or if you _must_ be robust against them, then either use `find` or – possibly better – use a more powerful language than `sh` to manage them (the fact that `sh` _can_ do everything doesn't mean that it's the best choice in each case). The shell is designed for usability first.

Comment: I agree, in principle, about the usability, but this variant fails when you have a _filename_ with each newline inside. This can easily occur unnoticed, for example, when you copy and paste a line from a pdf in a GUI, So you only think to be avoided pathological _filenames_.

Comment: Moreover IMHO __It's easy to start to parse `ls`, but it is afoot of future problems.__ Often we make scripts that we will use later, when we already will forget their limit... (it's human, it's usual). I [proposed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284064/66388) a `find` example (with `-exec` and without pipe) even if I deem a better (because pure shell) answer the [cuonglm's one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283892/66388), solid  and posix compliant.

Comment: @Hastur: those future problems will arise anyway.  Lots of things in the system aren't robust against files with newlines.  E.g. try using `locate` or `make` on them.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'd do if, for some reason, I wanted to remove strip the `.png` suffix from a list of file names. I wouldn't put it into a script; instead I'd just type the command at the shell prompt. Doing so would be a reminder that I'm **assuming** "sane" file names. There are plenty of things I'll do in a one-off manual command, when I feel free to make assumptions about what's in the current directory, that I probably wouldn't do in a script that might be re-used in some other context.

Answer (score 10):

You can use only BASH commands to do that (without any external tools).

```
for file in *; do echo "${file%.*}"; done
```

This is usefully when you're without /usr/bin and works nice for filenames like
this.is.image.png and for all extensions.

Answer (score 8):

wasn't it enough?

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\.png//g'
```

or in general, this

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\.[a-z]*//g'
```

will remove all extensions

Comment: It was but the other solutions work too.

Comment: I meant to say, your question started with ls -1, so ls -1 should do that. :)

Comment: The `-1` is not necessary, being the default here.

Comment: @Rohail Abbas  But not every system has sed installed?

Comment: All Unix/Unix Like system has (or should have) `sed` installed as it is a mandatory utility by the standard.

Comment: @jilagre    -1 shows the files in vertical list,

Comment: Indeed, but `ls` does it anyway without that option when its output is not being a terminal, which is the case here.

Comment: __Warning__ `ls -1 | sed 's/\.[a-z]*//g'` will fail if there is a filename as `Image.png.jpg.png` cutting all the time the key (`.png`).  Under Unix are allowed _strange_ filenames as `The new art of working on .png?files and other formats.png` where the `?` is a newline character. Unfortunately all the solution that will simply pipe/parse the `ls` output will incur in problems managing such cases...

Comment: Why the `g` qualifier? You want to remove `\.png` only at the end of the line, not every time it appears.

Comment: Thank You  Working file ...

Answer (score 7):

### It is not safe to parse `ls` or to pipe `find`<sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls),[2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)]</sup>

It is not safe to parse (and to pipe) the output of `ls` or `find`, mainly because it possible to find in the *file names* non usual characters as the *newline*, the *tab*... Here a pure shell cycle will work<sup>[[cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283892/66388)]</sup>.
Even the `find` command *not piped* with the option `-exec` will work:

```
find ./*.png  -exec  basename {} .png  \;
```

**Updates/Notes**: You can use `find .` to search even for the hidden files, or `find ./*.png` to get only the not hidden ones. With `find *.png -exec ...` you can have problem in the case it was present a file named `.png` because find will get it as an option. You can add `-maxdepth 0` to avoid to descend in directories named as `Dir_01.png`, or `find ./*.png -prune -exec ...` when maxdepth is not allowed (thanks Stéphane). If you want to avoid to list those directories you should add the option `-type f` (which would also exclude other types of non-regular files). Give it a look to the `man` for a more complete panorama about all the options available, and remember to check when they are POSIX compliant, for a better portability.

#### Some words more

It can happen, for example, that copying the title from a document and pasting into the filename, one or more newline will finish in the filename itself.  We can be even so unlucky that a title can contain even the key we have to use just before a newline:

```
The new art of working on .png
files and other formats.
```

If you want to test, you can create file names like this with the commands

```
touch "A file with two lines"$'\n'"and This is the second.png"
touch "The new art of working on .png"$'\n'"files and other formats.png"
```

The simple `/bin/ls *png` will output `?` instead of the non printable characters

```
A file with two lines?and This is the second.png
The new art of working on .png?files and other formats.png
```

In all the cases in which you will **pipe the output** of `ls` or `find` the following command will have no hint to understand if the present line comes from a new *file name* or if it follows a *newline* character in the precedent *file name*. A *nasty* name indeed, but still a legal one.

A shell cycle with a shell Parameter-Expansion , `${parameter%word}`, in both the variant with `printf` or `echo` will work <sup>[[cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283892/66388)],[[Anthon1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283891/66388)]</sup> .

> ```
> for f in *.png; do printf "%s\n" "${f%.png}" ; done
> ```

---

From the man page of the Shell Parameter Expansion <sup>[[3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)]</sup>

> ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>
> ... the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

Comment: Also the results of your `find` command are a bit variable (for example if there is a directory called `files.png`)

Comment: Dear @BroSlow, when I wrote the answer above  __I tried 13 (all) of the other variants present__ in that moment, by command line, in a script, launched as argument of a shell invocation. Please do the same and tell me if they behave in the way you expect. I did my tests  with `bash 4.3.11`, dash 0.5.7-4, zsh (when needed) 5.0.2.  Feel you free to read [this post](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that adds something more.  I agree about the note of _piping_ the output of `find`, for this I __expressly suggested `-exec`__, and I wrote in the title. `:-)`.

Comment: Re-read the wiki again. I still think you need to pipe in your example, since that's what's being discussed here. And for the majority of modern versions of `ls` there is no issue whatsoever when the output is piped or redirected, but as mentioned in wiki it may not work for all. Most will only insert the `?` in place of special characters when the output is sent to terminal. i.e. Do `echo *.png | od -c` and `ls *.png | od -c`. The newline issue is not an issue with `ls`, it's an issue with any command that doesn't null terminate across both sides of the pipe.

Comment: `printf  "${f%.png}\n"` is wrong. The first argument is the format, you shouldn't use variable data in there. Can even be seens as a DoS vulnerability (try with a `%1000000000s.png` file for instance).

Comment: You'd need `find ./*.png -prune -exec...` or you'd have problems with filenames starting with `-` (and files of type directory, note that `-maxdepth` is not portable)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Thanks, for `prune` I often risk to remain closed in my little gnu world... but even more for the DoS, I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rev`:

```
ls -1 | rev | cut -f 2- -d "." | rev
```

`rev` reverses all the strings (lines); you cut everything after the first '.' and rev re-reverses the remnant.

If you want to `grep` 'alma':

```
ls -1 | rev | cut -f 2- -d "." | rev | grep 'alma'
```

Comment: The `-1` is not necessary, being the default here.

Comment: This fails badly on a file named `My.2016.Summer.Vacation.png`

Comment: @DavidConrad my bad :/ I have corrected to `cut -f 2-`

Comment: Now it works with that file but not yet  with a file with `.png` and a newline just after...   It is suggested to avoid to parse `ls` because it love to hide well the surprises... :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I knew the directory only had files with .png as an extension, I would have just run: `ls | awk -F. '{print $1}'`

This will return the first "field" for anything where there is a filename.extension.

Example:

```
[rsingh@rule51 TESTDIR]$ ls
10.png  1.png  2.png  3.png  4.png  5.png  6.png  7.png  8.png  9.png

[rsingh@rule51 TESTDIR]$ ls | awk -F. '{print $1}'
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will fail on all the _filenames_ with more than one `.`, as `Image.1.png` and even on the ones with _not nice names_, with special characters inside. as the newline or the one that you will use as (input) record separator in `awk`, `RS`. It is suggested to avoid to parse the `ls` output because it loves to hide problem that will arise when you will not expect. You can read more in those reference [1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) or [2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). BTW nice the idea to use awk... I put some examples in one answer.

Comment: True, however, given the sample provided by Colin it would work just fine.

To make it work for the case you suggested, I'd probably change it to:

[rsingh@rule51 TESTDIR]$ ls | sed -e 's/.png$//'
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
harry.the.bunny
whats.a.png.filename

Not trying to be difficult, but given Colin's need, I'm not sure what the issue would be parsing ls.

Comment: sorry...

I just realized I didn't show the directory with the files prior to sed modifying the output of 'ls'

[rsingh@rule51 TESTDIR]$ ls
10.png  2.png  4.png  6.png  8.png  harry.the.bunny.png
1.png   3.png  5.png  7.png  9.png  whats.a.png.filename.png

[rsingh@rule51 TESTDIR]$ ls | sed -e 's/.png$//'
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
harry.the.bunny
whats.a.png.filename

Comment: __note1__ you need to escape the `.` in `\.` inside the `sed -e 's/\.png$//'`, but so it becomes an answer just written. :-(  __note2__ you can try to use `awk` with something like `ls | awk -F. '{if ($NF=="png") {for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++) printf("%s.", $i) ; printf $(NF-1)"\n"}}'`... but you will have always the problem that awk cannot know if the line is arriving is following or not a newline inside the file name. I tried to say better in my  answer.

Comment: Thanks Hastur, I missed that :).

Also, I ditched the use of awk in favor of sed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

according to your comment " I have a text file where where all the names are listed without the extension. I want to make a PHP script that compares the text file with the folder to see which file is missing " :

```
for file in $(cat yourlist) ; do
  [ -f "${file}.png" ] || {
    echo "$file : listed in yourlist, but missing in the directory"
  }
done
#assumes that filenames have no space...
# otherwise use instead:
#  while IFS= read file ; do ...(same inner loop as above)... ; done < yourlist
```

and the reverse:

```
for file in *.png ; do
  grep "^${file%.png}$" yourlist >/dev/null || {
    echo "$file: present in the directory but not listed in yourlist"
  }
done
#I assume there are no spaces/tabs/? before/after names in 'yourlist'. Change the script accordingly if there are some (or sanitize the list)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l | sed 's/\.png$//'`

Is the most accurate method as highlighted by @roaima. Without the escaped `\.png` files named `a_png.png` would be listed as : `a_`.

Comment: using `ls -l`, as you do, gives the file details, that is not what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

A simple shell line (ksh, bash or zsh; not dash):

```
set -- *.png; printf '%s\n' "${@%.png}"
```

A simple function (from No Extension):

```
ne(){ set -- *.png; printf '%s\n' "${@%.png}"; }
```

Or a function that remove any extension given (png by default):

```
ne(){ ext=${1:-png}; set -- *."$ext"; printf '%s\n' "${@%.${ext}}"; }
```

Use as:

```
ne jpg
```

If the output is an asterisk `*`, no file with that extension exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following feed awk the output of ls your superator is the "." and since all your files will have name.png you print the first column:
  `ls | awk -F"." '{print $1}'`

Answer (score -1):

If you have acccess to sed, this is better as it will strip the last file extension, no matter what it is (png, jpg, tiff, etc...)

```
ls | sed -e 's/\..*$//'
```

Comment: Breaks for filenames like `this.is.a.dotty.txt`. Try `s/\.[^.]*$//` instead.